# unexpected direction of z-axis (no view, no projection matrices)

Tags: opengl, orthographic

I'm trying to understand how one can draw objects using OpenGL. Question is quite simple, but still I can not find a definite answer to it anywhere (or I'm completely dumb :) ). Let me describe the issue.

1) I'm simply putting 2 triangles on the screen. Triangles' coordinates (x,y,z,w) are as follows:

```
Triag1 = { {0, 0, -0.5, 1} , {1, 0, -0.5, 1}, {0, 1, -0.5, 1} } // a bigger one
Triag2 = { {0, 0, 0.5, 1} , {0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}, {0, 0.5, 0.5, 1} } // a smaller one
```

2) I'm not using nor view, nor projection transforms

3) I'm passing 'default' color for each triangle as one of vertex attributes and simply bypass them to fragment shader using a varying. Triag1 is blue, Triag2 is red

All tutorials around the net say that OpenGL uses right-handed coordinate system and that Z-axis points 'out-of-the-screen'. So, considering respective z-coordinates of my objects, I expect to see a smaller red triangle and a bigger blue one behind it. How ever it isn't happening. I can only see a big fat blue triangle.

If I swap respective z-coordinates of my triangles (Triag1 gets positive z-coordinates, Triag2 gets negative z-coordinates) I see what I expected to see. BUT. This means that somehow Z-axis points INTO the screen, not out of it.

Could someone more experienced please explain what fundamental aspect do I miss?

P.S. no GLUT, no GLM, no calls to setup various OpenGL matrices. Only "pass vertices to GPU - enable shader program - draw the thing"

Answer (score 2):

> All tutorials around the net say that OpenGL uses right-handed coordinate system and that Z-axis points 'out-of-the-screen'.

That is just a convention - and a convention which really doesn't apply here as that is the convention for the *eye space*. Typically, you have some eye space where the camera looks along -z direction (and the `gluLookAt()` function is exactly designed with that in mind).

The typical projection matrix also flips the handedness as a side effect. And the `gluPerspective()`, `glOrtho()` and `glFrustum()` functions actually expect you to secify positive values for the `near` and `far` parameters, but set the near and far planes at `z=-near` and `z=-far` respectively.  So, the *clip space* of GL is typically considered as being left-handed. As you use no transformation matrices, you directly draw in clip space.

However, this is just another convention, and it could be changed, if you really want. You could flip around the depth test function, or you could flip it using `glDepthRange()`. In the end, it is all up to you. But usually, people stick with GL conventions and a left handed clip space, NDC and window space. It is actually quite intuitiv to have the near plane at z=0 and the far plane at z=1 in window coordinates.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I do not use nor GLUT, nor GLM, nor other extensions, (except for GLX, but it has nothing to do with 3d). Wanna try to do everything 'by-hand' to get some deeper understanding. No calls to glOrtho() and glFrustum() had been made as well. Just raw "pass vertices to GPU - enable shader program - draw the thing".

So, if I got you right, if I don't set anything up, the NDC space is left-handed by default?

Comment: @PeterGlushkov: yes. in NDC space, z=-1 is the near plane, and z=1 the far plane, by default.